# How to set Eval("DropDownList.SelectedItem.text") programmatically to gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval, dynamic-binding

aspx.cs file is:
[image: design]

CS file code:

[image]
My marks database structure is marks`(Standard varchar(20),Type_of_Exam varchar(20),telugu varchar(20),hindi varchar(20),eng......)`

I give those subjects in `dropdown` list items like telugu,hindi,english,.....

I use `gridview` to show that subject marks.My Question is.

I give `gridview` header name `"subject"` ;
How to give `"eval"` function to that `subject`.
That has to show `telugu` marks when i am select `telugu` item in `dropdownlist` and show  `hindi` marks when i am select `hindi` marks.

Thanks in Advance for spending time to read my question.
How can i dynamically bind `gridview` based on the values from the drop drop down list?.

Comment: please show us some code of what you've already tried

Comment: HI i tried to add image but it not shows.May i know what kind of information do you want?

Comment: Show us your gridview markup, and any code behind you have.

Comment: Now i add my code file.please observe.Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried  SelectedValue=<%# Eval("Yourcolumnname") %>

Comment: if i use column name.every time it gives that column related data only(like if telugu is used only telugu values is shown.what about hindi and remainig subjects.)

Answer (score 0):

In .aspx

'<%# DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text %>'

**WITHOUT** the `Eval` Or DoubleQuotes. you are just exposing server-side control property and you don't need to use Eval as you are not evaluating an expression from a bound Data-item.

You can also use the RowCreated event or RowDataBound for your gridview :

```
protected void MyGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //DoWhatever you Need
    TextBox t = e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("subject") as TextBox;
    t.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;   
}
```